# Issues with connecting to our domain

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, active-directory, windows-server

Info (for display purposes, none of this information is actually the same):

Domain name: THE-DOMAIN.local

NetBIOS Name: THE-DOMAIN

Local IP: 192.168.0.2

VPN IP: 10.0.0.2

---

the-domain.local is never found on our VPN or local devices - I have the windows DNS server installed, and my DNS server is pointing towards the servers

---

I am attempting to connect to my domain, and I keep getting these errors:

[Using the NetBIOS Name]

```
Note: This information is intended for a network administrator. If you are not your network's administrator, notify the administrator that you have received this information, which has been recorded in the file C:\Windows\debug\dcdiag.txt.

The domain name "the-domain" might be a NetBIOS domain name. If this is the case, verify that the domain name is properly registered with WINS.

If you are certain that the name is not a NetBIOS domain name, then the following information can help you troubleshoot your DNS configuration.

The following error occurred when DNS was queried for the service location (SRV) resource record used to locate an Active Directory Domain Controller (AD DC) for domain "the-domain":

The error was: "DNS name does not exist." (error code 0x0000232B RCODE_NAME_ERROR)

The query was for the SRV record for
_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.the-domain

Common causes of this error include the following:

- The DNS SRV records required to locate an AD DC for the domain are not registered in DNS. These records are registered with a DNS server automatically when an AD DC is added to a domain. They are updated by the AD DC at set intervals. This computer is configured to use DNS servers with the following IP addresses:

8.8.4.4
8.8.8.8
10.0.0.2

- One or more of the following zones do not include delegation to its child zone:

the-domain . (the root zone)
```

[Using the domain name]

```
Note: This information is intended for a network administrator. If you are not your network's administrator, notify the administrator that you have received this information, which has been recorded in the file C:\Windows\debug\dcdiag.txt.

The following error occurred when DNS was queried for the service location (SRV) resource record used to locate an Active Directory Domain Controller (AD DC) for domain "the-domain.local":

The error was: "DNS name does not exist." (error code 0x0000232B RCODE_NAME_ERROR)  Rest is the same
```

`DNS name does not exist` - This is starting to get on my nerves, I don't see why it isn't working, I can't access the device at all from the domain name (for any service).

I don't want to resort to editing the host file.

(I tried connecting on my laptop using the VPN/Virtual Network at the moment, I am not able to access my desktop and connect via LAN. I am able to connect to the server using RDP and VMWare Workstation, but I cant access the physical LAN; I will tell you when I am able to).

EDIT: I've created a windows 10 VM as well. So now I have a LAN device while I'm out

EDIT 2: After poking around on the DNS server, now can actually get to typing the-domain and join, then told to login. But after I login I get `The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted`

Comment: I need to sort the issue of resolving the-domain.local

Comment: bump.............